# windows python install Wagtail UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' Codec Fails to Decode Byte

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, wagtail

I'm getting an error when trying to install Wagtail on Windows 10.

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' Codec Fails to Decode Byte`

System environment:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.6.5
- Django 2.0.6

The error:

```
Collecting wagtail
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/7e/7f54fa12abad0399247e4dfa00e05aeaa3b7cf80dcab7e8653950878c79e/wagtail-2.1-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4<5.0,>=4.5.1 in d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from wagtail) (4.6.0)
Collecting django-treebeard<5.0,>=4.2.0 (from wagtail)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/8a/d3d85018bb14cf951a41f362da1505e0523ff8b798844e270f030d4646ac/django-treebeard-4.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Django<2.1,>=1.11 in d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from wagtail) (2.0.6)
Collecting Willow<1.2,>=1.1 (from wagtail)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/de/5dba65cdd859e5bc4e758e5fdb095f5770c9e2ddcc44679bcb54a714925d/Willow-1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting draftjs-exporter<3.0,>=2.0 (from wagtail)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/98/2ae0db16e3841d9d0623b1a2248987e1edd037ab7eaa04e45e4fdf18873b/draftjs_exporter-2.1.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "D:\Temp\pip-install-szjmba64\draftjs-exporter\setup.py", line 38, in <module>
        long_description = f.read()
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 1958: illegal multibyte sequence

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in D:\Temp\pip-install-szjmba64\draftjs-exporter\
```

How can I fix this so my installation completes successfully?

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: Windows10 python3.6.5 encountered an error while installing wagtail